# Writing to IIS using Command Line

Tags: iis-7, batch-file, iis-6, iis-5

I am trying to install application using a script. This application creates a virtual directory under Default Web Site in IIS. 
I have written this script. Is this right script or i am missing some thing.

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
msiexec /qb /i ZFPSetup.msi INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files (x86)\Application" TARGETVDIR="ZFP" WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX=1 /l*v "C:\log.txt"
iisvdir /create Default Web Site ZFP C:\Program Files (x86)\Application\ZFP 
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Application\StartKaraf.bat" echo error
```

I am getting below error:

```
MSI (s) (28:D0) [04:25:58:897]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIF886.tmp, Entrypoint: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: Site not found for create application
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: Failed to configure IIS application.
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80070002: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges Failed.
CustomAction WriteIIS7ConfigChanges returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Error 0x80070002: Site not found for create application

Maybe this is caused by the lack of quotes, so instead of:

> ... iisvdir /create Default Web Site ...

Try:

> ... iisvdir /create "Default Web Site" ...

Answer (score 0):

Using simple batch files is not the best way to go about configuring IIS. For system administration tasks such as this, Microsoft created [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Check out how to configure IIS using PowerShell here: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell.

Here's an example of how to use PowerShell to create a virtual directory in IIS:

```
PS IIS:\> New-Item 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\DemoVirtualDir1' -type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath c:\test\virtualDirectory1
```

The code above uses the [PowerShell Snap-In for Creating Applications](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools).

Good luck!

Comment: i am not good at powershell. I got this script from somewhere. What changes do i need to do to this script if i have to include above funtionality + uninstall and installation. Can you please help.

Comment: the script is too long to past here. can u please give me a powershell script.